# New pipe placeholder _ inside mutate (transform) function

Tags: r, dplyr

Can someone explain to me how to call the new pipe placeholder `_` inside a function, inside mutate? Here is a silly example:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris |>
  mutate(n_rows = nrow(x = _))
```

```r
Error in mutate(iris, n_rows = nrow(x = "_")) : 
  invalid use of pipe placeholder
```

Comment: For this particular code we can write `iris |> mutate(n_rows = n())` or `iris |> mutate(n_rows = nrow(x = cur_data()))` to work around the problem.

Comment: That's fine for the "silly example" exposed, but doesn't fulfill the post purpose.

Comment: I didn't knew of the existence of `cur_data()` though.

Comment: Another workaround is `iris |> list(. = _) |> with(mutate(., n_nrows = nrow(x = .)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an anonymous function instead; gives the intended transformed data frame.

```
iris |>
  {\(.) transform(., n_rows=nrow(x=.))}()
```

or

```
iris |>
  {\(.) dplyr::mutate(., n_rows=nrow(x=.))}()

#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species n_rows
# 1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa    150
# 2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa    150
# 3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa    150
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is sort of what I was looking for. Do the curly braces create a environment for the anonymous function to exist? I don't get it.

Comment: @dzegpi Yes, you can think of it this way; the anonymous function gets defined in those braces (which BTW also may be round, but I've seen somewhere that curlies are faster) and `iris` placed behind as argument. The whole thing gets interpreted as `{\(.) transform(., n_rows=nrow(x=.))}(iris)` which also won't work with whatsoever braces.

Answer (score 2):

The native pipe placeholder `_` cannot be used in nested calls, that is why you are getting this error.

You could something like this to make it work:

```r
iris |>
  nrow() |>
  transform(iris, x = _)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't for 2 reasons:

1. The base pipe can only pipe to one argument. In your example, you need the data frame to appear twice: `mutate(iris, n_rows = nrow(iris))`. This is possible with the `magrittr` pipe `%>%`, but not the base pipe `|>`.
2. As Maël says, you can't use `_` in a nested function call.

From the [R Release News](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) announcing `_`:

> In a forward pipe `|>` expression it is now possible to use a named argument with the placeholder `_` in the `rhs` call to specify where the `lhs` is to be inserted. The placeholder can only appear once on the `rhs`.